# SwiftUI @State not updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm very familiar with UIKit but just recently started working with SwiftUI. I have this very basic view coming from a `NavigationLink` and I can't figure out why this code does not work. I can't update that @State var`, I tried everything you can't think of. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks!

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var settingsEnabled: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print(oldValue)
            print("DID SET")
            print(settingsEnabled)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.settingsEnabled.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(String("\(self.settingsEnabled)"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code on Xcode-playground, but it threw me an error before getting compiled. Didn't you get any?

Comment: What error did you get? I have none

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `View` conformance.

```swift
struct Test: View {
...
}
```

Update: The seems to have occurred because you were using the `body` of the `Test` `struct` directly instead of the `Test` struct that conforms to `View` protocol, which in-turn contains the `settingsEnabled` `@State` variable.

Comment: Yep, sorry, removed by accident. It's present on the actual code, though :)

Comment: After adding `View` it's working perfectly fine no issues. `settingsEnabled` is getting toggled.

Comment: Hum so I guess it must be because this View is embedded in a NavigationLink, but I’ll test it on a playground and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Just figured out why! That's why it was working without the View conformance, I was actually using Test.body (which has the conformance) on ContentView. Thought this was the correct way to accomplish that :) Like I said, I'm still learning this new paradigm on my free time. Never knew however that this would have so much impact but I guess it makes sense. Do you want to expand on your answer regarding what I explained and I mark it as correct? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @Mykod I've updated the answer, although the question and answer seem to mismatch after the edit in the question. Would be better if you could revert the question to the previous version. Thanks.